# Vanity URLs in AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, amazon-cloudfront

I am looking for the recommended ways to create vanity URLs in AWS, I know of a way to create shortened links redirects using CloudFront + S3 as explained here:

https://www.intricatecloud.io/2019/09/create-your-own-short-link-redirects-using-cloudfront-s3/

What else?

Comment: Please define "vanity" URLs

Comment: @HussainMansoor A vanity URL is a descriptive, memorable and pronounceable URL usually used to redirect URLs from one location to another. In the simplest terms, a vanity URL is a long URL that has been converted into a customized short link. A vanity URL can also be known as a branded Link or a custom short URL.

Vanity URLs contain a domain name that features the brand or a relevant keyword for your business. These URLs can be used in a multitude of places, such as social media, emails, print publications, and other offline marketing activities.

Comment: vanity => url shortner

Comment: added explanation about architecture, if it helped you acceptance/upvote would hepl other others in future, also fell free to reach out if you need any help with code .

Answer (score 0):

I recently created a similar project which was completely serverless.
you can check it out at https://web.trym.fi/

I have divided it into 2 parts backend and frontend

Backend:-

- using sls framework to deploy lambda and api gateway.
- backend langauge nodejs/express
- lambda custom authorizer along with auth0 to handle authentication
- dynamodb to store original url and redirect url( short url)
- route 53 to create alias for api domain.

Front end

- frontend has been created using react
- it has been hosted by amplify which uses cloudfront behind the scenes

CI/CD

- has been handled by github actions, as well as staging for dev and production

architecture brief -

- user visits frontend app
- send request to backend api\
- backend converts url and stores to dynamodb
- sends back response to frontend

Note :- for trying api use this https://trym.fi/api-docs/